# WP7: Dynamically add items to a Grid

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7

I am trying to add multiple items in to a grid, so that later items will pop up underneath earlier items.

```
            TextBox foo = new TextBox();
            foo.Text = " " + id + " ";
            foo.Width = 440;
            foo.Height = 200;
            foo.VerticalAlignment = "Top";
            foo.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
            ((Grid)daysPanels[id].Content).Children.Add(foo);
```

Unfortunately, the `VerticalAlignment = "Top"` line isn't working, it says it can't implicitly convert type "String" to type "VerticalAlignment".  Am I doing this the right way and how can I fix that error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the [msdn documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.verticalalignment.aspx). VerticalAlignment is an enum.

```
foo.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top;
```